# I/O time when reading from HDFS in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I would like to measure the time taken for map and reduce when performing I/O (reading from HDFS) in Hadoop. I am using Yarn.
Hadoop 2.6.0.
What are the options for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need exact measurments - you could use [btrace](https://github.com/btraceio/btrace), add it as a javaagent to your tasks via `mapreduce.{map,reduce}.java.opts` - and then write script which measures whatever you like. Sample of btrace scripts are [here](https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/tree/master/samples).

Also there is [HTrace](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Tracing.html) - that might also be helpful.

Comment: I've got HTrace working, have you used it? I wonder how do I delimit the information I need..

Answer (score 1):

One rough estimation could be creating custom counters. For both mapper and reducer you could collect the timestamp when mapper(or reducer) starts processing and when it ends. From starting and ending timestamp, calculate and add it to custom counters, i.e mappers add to `MAPPER_RUNNING_TIME` and reducers add to `REDUCER_RUNNING_TIME` (or whatever name you would like to give it). When the execution is finished, subtract the aggregated value of your counters from `MILLIS_MAPS` and `MILLIS_REDUCES` respectively. You might need to look into Hadoop source code though to confirm if the staging time is or is not being included into `MILLIS_MAPS` and `MILLIS_REDUCES`. With this estimation you would need to take into account that the tasks are being executed concurrently, so the time will be rather total (or aggregated for all mappers and reducers).

I have not done this personally, but I think this solution could work unless you find better one.

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds good. I have found that MILLIS_MAPS =Total time spent by all maps (ms). I wonder if this also includes queue waiting time. What would this staging mean.

Comment: @AlexandruC. Unfortunately I cannot help you explaining much further, since it would require me to go through the source code and search how it is being calculated, which might be quite time consuming.

Comment: There is no need for you to do that. I'll do it.